# Weka Attribute Evaluator with multiple-attributes features

Tags: java, classification, weka, svm

I am classifying tweets using single-valued features (*e.g.* the number of followers of the user) and multiple-valued features (*e.g.* some long histogram, from LDA or Bag-of-Words for example).

I simply concatenate the features, modelling each component of each multiple-valued feature as a Weka Attribute.  I am using SVM and Naive Bayes.

The issue is this: I want to evaluate the attributes with Weka classes, I want to rank the multiple-valued feature as a single attribute (no sense get that BoF_1342 is better then LDA_4103 and BoF_242, and I only want know that BoF is better then LDA).

Does Weka support this kind of evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure WEKA supports this kind of aggregation.
The solution in this case would be for you to create a script that does it for you (not sure if you can even do that in you scenario)
Ex:
you have 4 attributes and three instances (BoF_1342,LDA_4103,BoF_242)

BoF_1342 0 - 0 - 0 - 1

LDA_4103 1 - 1 - 0 - 1

BoF_242  0 - 1 - 1 - 0

it would become

BoF 0 - 1 - 1 - 1

LDA 1 - 1 - 0 - 1